# Column Constraint error using SQLITE on android

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I'm trying to set up  a database and name the columns respectively, but I'm getting an error on line 16 with the PRIMARY KEY saying "')'  or coma expected got '_title'

```
public class MyDBHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION=1;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME="movies.db";
    public static final String TABLE_PRODUCTS="_movies";
    public static final String COLUMN_ID="_id";
    public static final String COLUMN_TITLE="_title";
    public static final String COLUMN_DATERELEASED="_dateReleased";
    public static final String COLUMN_FILENAME="_fileName";
    public MyDBHandler(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
        super(context, name, factory, version);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        //INFORMATION ABOUT EACH COLUMN FOR THE TABLE
        String query="CREATE TABLE "+TABLE_PRODUCTS+"("+
                COLUMN_ID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT "+
                COLUMN_TITLE+" TEXT "+
                COLUMN_DATERELEASED+"TEXT "+
                COLUMN_FILENAME+" TEXT "
                +" ); ";
        db.execSQL(query);
    }
```

Comment: `CREATE TABLE` is a SQL *statement*, not a *query*, so variable would be better named `sql` or `statement`, not `query`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is wrong you forgot to set comma .
Your query is like this

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        //INFORMATION ABOUT EACH COLUMN FOR THE TABLE
        String query="CREATE TABLE "+TABLE_PRODUCTS+"("+
                COLUMN_ID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "+
                COLUMN_TITLE+" TEXT, "+
                COLUMN_DATERELEASED+"TEXT, "+
                COLUMN_FILENAME+" TEXT "
                +" ); ";
        db.execSQL(query);
    }
```

Comment: `CREATE TABLE` is a SQL *statement*, not a *query*.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add comma after each column. Your Query String should be

```
String query="CREATE TABLE "+TABLE_PRODUCTS+"("+
                COLUMN_ID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "+
                COLUMN_TITLE+" TEXT, "+
                COLUMN_DATERELEASED+"TEXT, "+
                COLUMN_FILENAME+" TEXT "
                +" )";
```